# Toggle background_opacity option in alacritty

Tags: linux, shell, terminal-emulator

I want to bind key that switchs `background_opacity` value between 0.9 and 1.0 and immedialty shows the result in Alactitty terminal.
There is no action in key_bindings for this purpose.

I have `live_config_reload` enabled, so one possible approach is write zsh function, that will change  `alacritty.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened upon this question while looking for the same feature and ended up implementing it myself. I have included a demo of the working in my [blog](https://trunc8.github.io/2021/08/08/tut-toggle-alacritty-opacity).

For completeness, I will include the steps here.

###### ~/bin/toggle_alacritty_opacity

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## If alacritty.yml does not exist, raise an alert
[[ ! -f ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml ]] && \
    notify-send "alacritty.yml does not exist" && exit 0

## Fetch background_opacity from alacritty.yml
opacity=$(awk '$1 == "background_opacity:" {print $2; exit}' \
    ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml)

## Assign toggle opacity value
case $opacity in
  1)
    toggle_opacity=0.9
    ;;
  *)
    toggle_opacity=1
    ;;
esac

## Replace opacity value in alacritty.yml
sed -i -- "s/background_opacity: $opacity/background_opacity: $toggle_opacity/" \
    ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml
```

Make the above script executable by running in the terminal:
`chmod +x ~/bin/toggle_alacritty_opacity`

Ensure that you have the following line in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`

```sh
## In order to use the executable scripts inside ~/bin directly
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now running `toggle_alacritty_opacity` from your terminal will toggle alacritty's opacity.

##### Bonus

If you're using i3 WM, append the following lines to `~/.config/i3/config`

```sh
## Toggling alacritty opacity in i3 (inside ~/bin)
bindsym $mod+Shift+a exec --no-startup-id toggle_alacritty_opacity
```

Now you have a key binding to toggle alacritty's opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Works Well!

I modified this script a little suit for me. Also added some cases so I don't have only two values to switch between.

This is called from my Left Window Manager [LeftWM] config.

**~/.config/leftwm/config.ron**

```rust
keybind: [
...
(command: Execute, value: "~/bin/opacitytoggle", modifier: ["modkey", "Shift"], key: "a"),
...
],
```

**~/bin/opacitytoggle**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## If alacritty.yml does not exist, raise an alert
[[ ! -f ~/.config/alacritty.yml ]] && \
    notify-send "alacritty.yml does not exist" && exit 0

## Fetch background_opacity from alacritty.yml
opacity=$(awk '$1 == "opacity:" {print $2; exit}' \
    ~/.config/alacritty.yml)

## Assign toggle opacity value
case $opacity in
  0.0)
    toggle_opacity=0.55
    ;;
  0.55)
    toggle_opacity=0.70
    ;;
  0.70)
    toggle_opacity=0.85
    ;;
  0.85)
    toggle_opacity=1.0
    ;;
  1.0)
    toggle_opacity=0.0
    ;;
    *)
      toggle_opacity=1.0
    ;;
esac

## Replace opacity value in alacritty.yml
sed -i -- "s/opacity: $opacity/opacity: $toggle_opacity/" \
    ~/.config/alacritty.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MacOS using [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) that emulates the `CMD` + `U` keyboard shortcut in iTerm2

Add this to your `.hammerspoon/init.lua`

```lua
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "U", function()
  alacritty_file_name = string.format("%s/.config/alacritty.yml", os.getenv("HOME"))

  opaque = "opacity: 1"
  transparent = "opacity: 0.9"

  local file = io.open(alacritty_file_name)

  local content = file:read "*a"
  file:close()

  if string.match(content, opaque) then
    content = string.gsub(content, opaque, transparent)
  else
    content = string.gsub(content, transparent, opaque)
  end

  local fileedited = io.open(alacritty_file_name, "w")
  fileedited:write(content)
  fileedited:close()
end)
```

Make sure to adjust line 2 to reflect the right location of the `alacritty.yml` file (script assumes `~/.config/alacritty.yml`)

Also make sure the `alacritty.yml` file contains

```yaml
windows:
  opacity: 1
```